# Register Application in Azure AD(App registrations) Using API?

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to register application in Azure AD(App registrations) using API in .net core 2.0.
I have tried to registered application using power-shell. it is  working. but I need to do that using API because power-shell script will have authorization issue when we deploy it on web server.

Is there any API using which we can register API?

I have tried to find Microsoft Graph API but I did not find any example. I have also tried to find sample example but they are using power-shell script to application registration.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: Hi Harish, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Hury, my problem is not solved till now. As per your answer I have did the changes. but the problem is how can i generate clientId and clientSecrete b'c I am creating new application. To solve that problem I have created one application in azure AD using azure portal and using that clientId and clientsecret I try to create new app through code but it gives me exception that "Insufficient privileges". Now, I am trying to find out what type privilege they required & how can give it?

Comment: Hi @Harish Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your requirement, you can use microsoft graph [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications`.

To use this api, you need to finish authorization. As you are worry about authorization, I suggest you to use client_credential grant flow to do it. You can refer to the code below in the document of the graph api to request the api by sdk.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var application = new Application
{
    DisplayName = "Display name"
};

await graphClient.Applications
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(application);
```

By the way, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) to know how to get the `authProvider` in the code above.

[image]

=================================**Update**===============================

You need to add the permission to the application which you created. We can find the [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) requires the permissions as below:

[image]

So we need to add at least one of the permissions to the application you created, please refer to the steps below:

[image]

[image]

After add the permission, do not forget grant admin consent.

[image]

After that, run your code. It will create the new app success.

=======================**Update for add permissions**===================

To create a app with some permissions, you can use the code below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp28
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<client id>")
            .WithTenantId("<tenant id>")
            .WithClientSecret("<client secret>")
            .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            
            var application = new Application
            {
                DisplayName = "huryNewappWithPermissions",
                RequiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>()
                {
                    new RequiredResourceAccess
                    {
                        ResourceAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
                        ResourceAccess = new List<ResourceAccess>()
                        {
                            new ResourceAccess
                            {
                                Id = Guid.Parse("e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"), //id of User.Read(Delegated) permission
                                Type = "Scope"
                            },
                            new ResourceAccess
                            {
                                Id = Guid.Parse("1bfefb4e-e0b5-418b-a88f-73c46d2cc8e9"), //id of Application.ReadWrite.All(Application) permission
                                Type = "Role"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Applications.Request().AddAsync(application);
        }
    }
}
```

You can list all of graph permissions by this api:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

Then find the id of permissions and put the it into the code above. `Type = "Scope"` means the permission is "Delegated" type, `Type = "Role"` means the permission is "Application" type.

Comment: Hi Hury, Thanks for your effort.I have done this.after grant admin consent it is working in my personal account.but at my organization directory i don't have right to give admin consent.so, can't do that. is there any other way without give admin consent? like once user login with their azure AD credential can i use that token to create application. b'c while you create app in azure portal. we don't need admin consent.Is there any other way to do that? Thanks again for your efforts.

Comment: Hi @Harish I'm afraid we can't do it without grant admin consent. Create a new application and assign the permissions to it is necessary. So you have to ask the admin user in your organization directory to do grant admin consent.

Comment: How can give "API permission" while creating application? Or how can update application to give 'API permission"?

Comment: @HarishShisode I will  do some research and come back.

Comment: Hi @HarishShisode Please refer to my latest update. We can create the app with permissions by the code, but you still need to ask admin user do grant admin consent.

Comment: Hi @Hury thanks for this sample application. it is very helpful for me.yes I will asked admin user for admin consent. b'c I don't find any other option to do that without admin consent.Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Hurry, the code which you have given is working fine. but i need to add "user_impersonation"(Key-Vault) delegate permission  as per code to add resource need id(Guid) but for "user_impersonation"(Key-Vault) delegate permission there is no guid. how i can find id for that? and another question Q. using "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" resourceAppId can i add "user_impersonation"(Key-Vault)" permission? Thanks!

Comment: @HarishShisode You can find `user_impersonation` permission by this api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals?$filter=appId eq 'cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093'`. You can modify your code, change the `ResourceAppId` to `cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093` and use the id of the permission which response from the search api.